# Create an image from a volume snapshot using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

We're using [actions-runner-controller](https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller#about) to deploy self-hosted runners as pods in GKE for github actions. Everything is specified in terraform including the GKE cluster that backs the runners.

The pods are managed by stateful sets so that we can mount a volume snapshot, which is a cache of stuff that jobs might need, e.g. common actions, cli tools etc.

We’re hitting rate limits in relation to snapshot creation (`RESOURCE_OPERATION_RATE_EXCEEDED`). It seems that we’re attempting to create a snapshot for each CI job that runs, whereas we [should be creating an image from a snapshot and creating a persistent volume from that](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#freq-create-disks).

However, it's not clear to me how this can be done in terraform.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but we're using [Node Auto Provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) to provision the nodes on which the pods run.

Any guidance would be appreciated...

Comment: Any luck on htis?

Comment: not really. i think you'd need to use the gcloud cli the create the image and then it's not clear how this could be used to dynamically create PVs.